# Cross-reference to appendix sections in elsarticle document class

Tags: cleveref, elsarticle

I am trying to reference a result given in the appendix, but `cleveref` is giving "Appendix Appendix" (doubling it). A way to solve this problem is to add `\def\appendixname{}`.

Not surprisingly, this also eliminates the name "Appendix" from the section title. How can I solve the problem while still keeping "Appendix" in the section title?

MWE:

main.tex

```
\documentclass[final,times,letterpaper,authoryear,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{etex,etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{environ}
\crefname{lem}{lemma}{lemmas}
\crefname{prop}{Proposition}{Propositions}
\crefname{thr}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefname{cor}{Corollary}{Corollaries}
\crefname{ass}{Assumption}{Assumptions}
\crefname{df}{Definiton}{Definitons}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[letterpaper,layout=letterpaper]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\subfile{testa}

\appendix
\subfile{appendix}
\subfile{appendixb}

\end{document}
```

testa.tex

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
This is an introduction. From now on we will hold Result A and B as true. We prove Result A in \Cref{regsol} and we prove Result B in \Cref{regsolB}.
```

appendix.tex

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\def\appendixname{}

\begin{document}

\section{Proof of Result A}\label{regsol}
We show that...

\end{document}
```

appendixb.tex

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\section{Proof of Result B}\label{regsolB}
We show that...

\end{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `elsarticle` document class redefines the `\thesection` macro in a quick and unfortunately rather dirty way when `\appendix` is executed:

```
\gdef\thesection{\appendixname\@Alph\c@section}
```

[Update mid-2020: The instruction in the most recent version of `elsarticle.cls` is

```
\gdef\thesection{\appendixname~\@Alph\c@section}
```

The only difference, relative to the code in the original form of my answer, is the insertion of an unbreakable space after `\appendixname`.]

This prefixes the word "Appendix" to the (Alpha-stye) section "number" (A, B, C, etc.) That's what's causing the cross-reference call-outs generated by `cleveref` to contain the string "Appendix" twice.

A quick fix consists of using the instruction `\labelcref` instead of `\cref` when making cross-references to sections located in the appendix part of the document.

A more elaborate fix, i.e., one which lets you continue to use `\Cref` and `\cref` to cross-reference sections in the appendix, involves inserting the following code block immediately after the `\appendix` instruction:

```
\gdef\thesection{\Alph{section}} % corrected redefinition of "\thesection"
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\appendixname\ \csname the#1\endcsname.\hspace{0.5em}}
\makeatother
```

A separate comment: The preamble of your document is, to put it delicately, not organized all that well. For instance, you provide the option `times` to the `\documentclass` instruction; this option tells LaTeX to load the "Times Roman" font. Later, you load the `lmodern` font package, which loads the "Latin Modern" font family, followed by a loading of the `kpfonts` font package, which loads a clone of the "Palatino" font family. Which font family do you want? You may want to go through the preamble and determine which packages are really needed.

---

Here's an MWE that illustrates the workings of the "more elaborate fix" shown above. (I've simplified the preamble and the body of your test document in order to focus on the essentials.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

We prove Result A in \Cref{regsol} and we prove Result B in \Cref{regsolB}.

\appendix
%% now insert the new code block
\gdef\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\appendixname\ \csname the#1\endcsname.\hspace{0.5em}}
\makeatother


\section{Proof of Result A}\label{regsol}
We show that \dots

\section{Proof of Result B}\label{regsolB}
We show that \dots

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you spot any other inconsistency/problem besides the fonts?

Comment: @capadocia - For sure, don't load a package twice -- see `amssymb` -- and do make an effort to load the `hyperref` and `cleveref` packages last. Since I don't know anything about the *contents* your document, I'm not in a position to judge whether the other packages you load are really needed. I somehow doubt, though, that *all* of them are needed. That's why I suggested you go through the preamble and test the need of each package.

Comment: You made my day. Thanks @Mico

Comment: @Daniel - Many thanks for your compliment. :-) I took this opportunity to verify that the answer is still "correct", i.e., that the code in `elsarticle.cls` hadn't been updated since I wrote this answer about five years ago. It turns out that they did update the code -- but without actually fixing the underlying issue. Sigh.