How can I change the numbering of a lemma in Appendix?
Now I use [section] to number the theorems, lemmas,... In the main body, it looks well, but in Appendix, it shows like
Lemma Appendix A.1.
Is it possible to have the following form?
Lemma A.1.

\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\section{section}

\begin{lemma}
    Lemma in section
\end{lemma}

\appendix
\section{appendix}

\begin{lemma}
    Lemma in appendix
\end{lemma}


\end{document}



Please tell us which document class you employ, how the lemma environment is defined in the preamble (and with the help of which packages), and which instructions you use to inform LaTeX that there's a transition from the main body to the appendix. Ideally, you would edit your posting to add a minimal working example (aka an MWE) that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix.

Does your code maybe feature an instruction (upon entering the appendix portion of the document) such as \renewcommand{\thesection}{Appendix \Alph{section}}?

(updated answer after the OP revealed that the elsarticle document class is in use)
The elsarticle document class is known to redefine the \thesection macro in a rather faulty way when \appendix is executed:
\gdef\thesection{\appendixname~\@Alph\c@section}

This is faulty because LaTeX uses the macro \thesection in lots of places in addition to creating section-level headers. For instance, as the OP has (re)discovered, \thesection is used in the two-part numbers of lemmas, theorems, corollaries, etc that include the current section number.
What's needed, then, is an approach that prefixes \appendixname to the section number (or should that be "letter"?) in section-level headers in the appendix portion of the document without improperly modifying \thesection.
Taking onboard the discussion in this answer to the 2015 posting Cross-reference to appendix sections in elsarticle document class [shameless self-citation alert!], I suggest you add the following code block immediately after \appendix:
% New -- cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248707
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}} % corrected redefinition of '\thesection'
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\appendixname\ \csname the#1\endcsname.\hspace{0.5em}}
\makeatother


Sure enough, with this addition the OP's MWE produces this output:

\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Results}
\begin{lemma} Lemma in body of document. \end{lemma}

\appendix

% New -- cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248707
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}} % corrected redefinition of '\thesection'
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\appendixname\ \csname the#1\endcsname.\hspace{0.5em}}
\makeatother

\section{Supplemental material}
\begin{lemma} Lemma in appendix. \end{lemma}

\end{document}


Addendum: The code block suggested above will prefix the word "Appendix" to all levels of sectioning headers in the appendix. If you want the prefix to apply only to section-level headers, but not to subsection-level (and below) headers as well, I suggest you employ the following code block instead:
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}} % same as above
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname.\hspace{0.5em}}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%  enable individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\appendixname\ \thesection.\hspace{0.5em}}
\makeatother


Hi, thank you for the comments. I tried the code, but after inserting it, the numbering of the theorems, lemmas in the main body become "Theorem/Lemma Appendix xxx". I have added the MWE in the question. It is a template of Elsevier paper. Is this the problem?

@RuihaoWang - Please see my updated answer. It was very useful that you edited your posting (a) to mention that you employ the elsarticle document class and (b) to post an MWE.

It works now! Many thanks!
